# OpenCL : error -9999 on NVIDIA K20m

Tags: opencl, gpu, nvidia

I usually always find a solution on google (80% here), but this time this is unfortunately not the case. That's why I decided to create an account.

I have written an OpenCL code which runs on different Intel and AMD CPU. It runs on an AMD RADEON HD7970 and NVIDIA Quadro FX 1800M too. However when I try to launch the code on an NVIDIA K20m I get the error -9999 with "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel".

The most troubling is that the error occurs after 512 iterations (I guess 512 is a coincidence).

I believe (but maybe it was just error -11) I have already seen this error but it was an error during building program and due to "clGetEventProfilingInfo". This time all profiling is comment.

I'm looking for information about this error.
Thank you in advance for your answers.

### Platform info:

OpenCL version: 1.1
CUDA version: 7.0.18

P.S.: It may be useful to precise that I'm not an administrator of this system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

Generally, in a kernel we can READ at a non allocated place. In my case I have used this property in order to avoid a useless test which is bad in a kernel. This reading out of memory was the problem on the NVIDIA K20.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of future visitors from Google (on which this now has a very high ranking for this error code,) this is a vendor-specific error code from NVidia.

On [Stream HPC's list of OpenCL error codes](https://streamhpc.com/blog/2013-04-28/opencl-error-codes/), code `-9999` is listed for function `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` with the description:

> Illegal read or write to a buffer